# Check If Database is Open in Lua

Tags: database, sqlite, lua

How can I check with Lua to see if my connection to my sqlite database is still open?

Comment: What SQLite binding are you using? It's hard to tell, but generally, the connection is open as long as you keep a reference to the connection (have it in a variable) and do not call the `close` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LuaSQLite](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/home) and [LuaSQL](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/index.html) are the most widely spread SQLite libraries for Lua.

Using luasqlite it is:

```
sqlite3=require"sqlite3"
db1=sqlite3.open_memory()
db2=sqlite3.open_memory()
db2:close()
print("db1 is ".. (db1:isopen() and "is open" or "it's not open"))
print("db2 is ".. (db2:isopen() and "is open" or "it's not open"))
```

Using luasql with the sqlite backend:

```
sqlite3=require('luasql.sqlite3')
env=sqlite3.sqlite3()
con1=env:connect(':memory:')
con2=env:connect(':memory:')
con2:close()
print("con1 is ".. (tostring(con1):match'closed' and "not open" or "open"))
print("con2 is ".. (tostring(con2):match'closed' and "not open" or "open"))
```